# What does this line of code mean in this package-merge algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I find an algorithm [Package-Merge](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.157.4015%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=for%20all%20d%2C%20Ld%20list%20of%20items%20having%20width%202%5Ed%3B&ei=P-m1TbPUFenr0gH16OjxBA&usg=AFQjCNGrUCiZcTp2WgJQRijRyBi0ChN14Q&sig2=j3-ZtAK3ptliQ7qN_K-Z0g)

```
Algorithm(I, X) {
    S is empty;
    for all d, Ld list of items having width 2^d;
    while X > 0 loop 
        minwidth = the smallest term in diadic expansion of X; 
        if I=0 then //is empty 
            return “No solution.” ; 
        else 
            d=the minimum such that L is not empty;
            r=2^d; 
            if r > minwidth then 
                return “No solution.”
            else if r = minwidth then 
                Delete the minimum weight ; 
                X= X - minwidth ;
            end if 
            Pd+1=PACKAGE(Ld) ;
            discard Ld ; 
            Ld+l=MERGE(pd+1,Ld+1);
        end if 
    end loop 
    return “S is the optimal solution.”
}
```

I have some question about algorithm.
what is Ld+1?
why we discard Ld when it maybe have one coins that its value=minwidth when r

Comment: Can you understand anything from what you've just written?

Comment: The description is very confusing.

Comment: What language is this? Did you just copy this from a textbook? It looks like a theoretical example rather than a real one.

Comment: You made me work at that a little too hard.  Next time, could you provide a link to the algorithm that you're using, or at least give us the name of the algorithm?

Answer (score 5):

Ld + 1 is actually

> L<sub>d+1</sub>

[See here (A Fast Algorithm for Optimal Length-Limited
Huffman Codes)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.157.4015%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=for%20all%20d%2C%20Ld%20list%20of%20items%20having%20width%202%5Ed%3B&ei=P-m1TbPUFenr0gH16OjxBA&usg=AFQjCNGrUCiZcTp2WgJQRijRyBi0ChN14Q&sig2=j3-ZtAK3ptliQ7qN_K-Z0g)

It means the list entry at the location `d+1`.  So if d == 5, it's the *sixth list entry.*